# Configure python-coveralls

Tags: python, github, travis-ci, nosetests, coveralls

I have a github repo which is in python and I have builts its tests using nosetests. The problem is I am unable to configure coveralls for this. I tried everything according to docs but the coverage remains unknown. Here is the link to the repo [BinPy](http://github.com/BinPy/BinPy)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like everything is set up properly. Are you sure your coverage reports are compatible with coveralls? Try `coveralls --verbose` (which will upload the report and dump everything to stdout as well) to debug.